# Android - Change Textview if text didn't change for 5 seconds

Tags: java, android

I have a Textview that is being updated constantly by a method (updateviewAC) that gets a string from 2 other methods.
One of the methods(finalvalueAC) sets a Boolean to true the other (temporaryvalueAC)to false.
On updateviewAC I wanted to put a function that if the Boolean was true it would save the string to a variable and 5 seconds later test if that variable was equal to the textview text.
If it was equal it would change the textview text to a empty string " ".
Like that during long periods that there is no new value it wouldnt show anything.
I tried timers, handlers and loops but I can't manage to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView textView ;
Handler handler ;
String textViewString ;

public void testFunction(Boolean yourBoolean , String yourText) {


    //this is the given text from textview :

    textViewString = textView.getText().toString();


   // check the boolean :
    if(yourBoolean){
        
        
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(() -> {

            if (yourText.equals(textViewString)) {
                
                textView.setText("");
            }

        }, 5000);
       
    } 

}
```